# what does the return value of @Modifying methods in Spring Data JPA mean

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

```
@Repository
public interface LoginDao extends JpaRepository<LoginEntity, Integer> { //}, LoginDaoCustom {
    LoginEntity findByLogin(String login);

    @Modifying
    int changePassword(String password, String login);
}
```

If I change the return value of the changePassword to anything other than int, I get the error below.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Modifying queries can only use void or int/Integer as return type!
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:65)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$ModifyingExecution.<init>(JpaQueryExecution.java:166)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.getExecution(AbstractJpaQuery.java:106)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:86)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:337)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:155)
    ... 46 more
```

What does this integer return value mean ? I am sure spring has it documented somewhere, but I can't find it. It is not listed in the [jpa.modifying-queries](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.0.0.M1/reference/html/#jpa.modifying-queries)

I should add that if do declare the return type as int, the update fails silently and values aren't updated.

Comment: Can somebody elaborate on the negative vote please ?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The int/Integer return value is the number of rows that where updated in the database.

Comment: TY, is this a basic JDBC thing ? Would you kindly point me to some documentation ?

Comment: Yes, this is JDBC behavior. Check out this documentation http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Try the Spring Data JPA code and you'll see the same behavior if all goes well

Comment: By the way, you will need a @Query on your method in order to get it to work!

Comment: Oh, I had the `@NamedQuery` in the Entity. Method returns 1 but for some reason the record returned by `findAll` does not reflect the changes. I would have expected some error.

Comment: Maybe you should try some of the options of @Modifying

Comment: I tested and the return value is the accessed rows